# Material Datepicker css not working properly

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, datepicker

```
                  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                  </mat-form-field>
```

This is the component that I am trying to use
However my datepicker is not displaying as expected

[My Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s6lx.png)
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFsSk.png)

I tried using ngx-bootstrap 6.0.0
But still it is not helping
My Angular version is 10.2.3

Comment: It's looks like you're using a .css that have conficts names with the angular/material/themes/???.css. USe the tools navigator (F12) to check what css class have the "header" of the months